# New install 22.04 Desktop, "apt-get autoremove" breaks something and doesn't boot

Tags: 22.04, nvme

I reinstalled my desktop (was using 20.04 LTS) with 22.04 LTS. So normal clean install from USB drive..

I do a normal install and when done I open a terminal and do:

- apt-get update
- apt-get dist-upgrade
- reboot
- (after reboot all is still fine)
- apt-get dist-upgrade (to see if anything missing)
- apt-get autoremove

The output of the last dist-upgrade

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom3 libass9 libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libblas3 libbluray2 libbs2b0
  libchromaprint1 libcodec2-1.0 libdav1d5 libdpkg-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libigdgmm12 liblilv-0-0 libmfx1 libmysofa1 libnorm1
  libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvidia-encode-515 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515 libnvidia-gl-515 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.3-0 libpostproc55
  librabbitmq4 librubberband2 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libsrt1.4-gnutls libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libudfread0 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2
  libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libx265-199 libxnvctrl0 libxvidcore4 libzimg2 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-515 pkg-config pocketsphinx-en-us screen-resolution-extra va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulsedsp pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils sudo
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

Output from last autoremove

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom3 libass9 libavcodec58 libavformat58 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libblas3 libbluray2 libbs2b0
  libchromaprint1 libcodec2-1.0 libdav1d5 libdpkg-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libigdgmm12 liblilv-0-0 libmfx1 libmysofa1 libnorm1
  libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvidia-encode-515 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515 libnvidia-gl-515 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.3-0 libpostproc55
  librabbitmq4 librubberband2 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsord-0-0 libsratom-0-0 libsrt1.4-gnutls libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3 libswscale5 libudfread0 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2 libva-x11-2
  libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libx265-199 libxnvctrl0 libxvidcore4 libzimg2 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-515 pkg-config pocketsphinx-en-us screen-resolution-extra va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 76 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
After this operation, 656 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

After I do a reboot I see the following on the screen

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 217873/61022208 files, 7026862/244059136 blocks
[.     4.786323]
```

This is all I get on the screen, noting changes.

My initial install was with choosing LVM and encrypted disk during install. When I do this I get the following after entering the password for the encrypted disk

```
Press ctrl+c to cancel all file system checks in progress
```

and nothing happens.

Does the "autoremove" removes something critical? I don't see any recent mentions about this problem with ubuntu 22.04

Using a Samsung 980 1 TB, M.2 NVMe

I tried a couple of times by doing a new install. After the autoremove the problems is always the same.

Comment: It's removing your video drivers along with other important stuff. Are you sure you have listed every step you took? Why are you doing `dist-upgrade` instead of just `upgrade`?

Comment: Checking a random package: `pocketsphinx-en-us` is in Universe, not Main. It's simply not included with a stock install of Ubuntu Desktop 22.04. This suggests that your question has (misleading) omissions that make it unanswerable as currently written. Whatever your problem is, it's probably caused by what you didn't tell us.

Comment: I just tried again with another SSD. Standard install. When done I launch a terminal and only do "apt-get update", "apt-get dist-upgrade", "apt-get autoremove". And after reboot same problem. I do a "dist-upgrade" instead of "upgrade" to make sure I also have the newest kernel. Does three commando's should break anything right after a clean install?

Comment: During the install process I do check the checkbox for third party software

Comment: Please add new information to your Question above. Comments are not intended fro conversation. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is answerable.

Comment: Try troubleshooting: Install without third-party-software. Then apt update. Then apt autoremove. NO upgrade or dist-upgrade yet. Compare with your earlier result.

Comment: "I do a "dist-upgrade" instead of "upgrade" to make sure I also have the newest kernel." is flawed logic. Don't do `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Did a couple of installs. Here are the results:  
  
no 3th party during install: update, autoremove: works  
no 3th party during install: update, upgrade, autoremove: works  
no 3th party during install: update, dist-upgrade, autoremove: works  
3th party during install: update, upgrade, autoremove: works  
3th party during install: update, dist-upgrade, autoremove: breaks  
  
So problems is with some 3th party package. I will just use the install without 3th party.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-addons`

It seems selecting 'Install third-party' is not including ubuntu-restricted-addons package which sets its dependencies to those you have mentioned above.